# drupal error 500 when trying to add view ticker

Tags: drupal, view, content-management-system, drupal-6, drupal-modules

am making a website and want to add a view ticker, I have enabled this module, however when I click view ticker it comes up with this error. internal service error.

However when I click for example the HTML list, there is no errors.

any ideas why this is showing, or how it can be fixed.

[image: error]

As you can see on the image, when I want to enable to views ticker its given me the error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear cache!!

if that dont work, uninstall and then install again! that should do the trick.

and if that dont work might be permissions.